# JavaScript: Rounding question

Tags: javascript, rounding

If I have the following

```
var lowerBound = 0;
var higherBound = 100;
var inputVar = document.getElementById('input').value;  // e.g. 51
```

How do I programatically determine if the `inputVar` is closer to variable `lowerBound` or variable `higherBound`?

Meaning, if the user inputs '`51`', the function should return '`100`'. But if the user inputs '`49`', it should return '`0`'.

Answer (score 1):

Find the middle value for the upper and lower bounds then test.

```
function findNearest(num) {
 if((num - 0) !== num) throw "invalid test value";
 var lower = 0;
 var upper = 100;
 var middle = ( upper - lower ) / 2;
 return ( num > middle ? upper : lower );
}

findNearest(2); // lower
findNearest(15.465); // lower
findNearest(50); // lower
findNearest(51); // upper
findNearest(122); // upper
findNearest('asdasd'); // exception
findNearest(null); // exception
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not find the difference between lower and upper and then:

```
inputVar = document.getElementById('input').value < middleVal ? lowerBound : upperBound.
```

The only problem then is, what is the value of 50?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to decide whether you want a value of 50 to match the lower or upper bound yourself:

```
var inputVar = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input').value);
inputVar = (inputVar > 50) ? higherBound : lowerBound;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
var inputVar = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value, 10);
var rounded = (higherBound - inputVar) <= (inputVar - lowerBound) ? higherBound : lowerBound;
```

If you want 50 to round down to 0, then change `<=` to `<`.

Answer (score 0):

Or for the mathematically inclined :)

```
var rounded = Math.round(inputVar / 100) * 100;
```

50 is (mathematically correctly) rounded up to 100.

Comment: What about varying boundaries?

Comment: OK, if you want to be a stickler: Math.round((Math.max(0,inputVar) % 100) / 100) * 100;